# Jmeter did not record drop down box selection

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

As am new to Jmeter facing some problem in recording the `dropDownBox` selection.

Scenario:
Login ->Click on drop down box on Dashboard -> Select the drop down list item and click on `Create button` so that selected drop down page will be opened .

I want to check  the performance of drop down box selection i.e. how much time it is taking for selecting the list and click on create button  because manually it is taking too much for loading .

I have recorded the script using proxy server, but when I click on  drop down box am not able to list being selected in  the drop down  in the recording mode

While  Checking the `HTTP` Request , I am able to see some

"`/~/Scripts/jQueryDatePicker/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js` "

also recorded for the drop down list .

I guess the drop  down  box list is a js .

Is their any work around need to done for selecting the `dropdownbox` list item and click on `create` `button`?

Can you please help me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the front page of [Apache JMeter site](http://jmeter.apache.org/) the following mentioned:

> **JMeter is not a browser**
>
> JMeter is not a browser. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc, but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever viewed at a time).

Hence described scenario cannot be implemented using vanilla JMeter.

However a plugin which can kick off a real browser (it can be headless) so you will be able to measure your page performance. Check out [WebDriver Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/).

If you go the WebDriver Sampler way I recommend to check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](http://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide